# No Abbreviations in Bibliography with biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sbl

I am using `biblatex-sbl` and everything it does with shorthands is perfect, except the bibliography. My style guide states that no abbreviations should be used in the bibliography. This goes for things like `shortseries`, `shortjournal`, etc.

I tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442641/31561), but it did not work.

Here is a MWE with a few different entry types. I do not want the series to show up by itself in the bibliography, which is why it is set to `skipbib`. I put in two entries from the same series to show that the series is not in the bibliography.

```
documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}

@series{WBC,
   series      = {Word Biblical Commentary},
   shortseries = {WBC},
   options     = {skipbib},
}

@commentary{WBCExod,
   author      = {John I. Durham},
   title       = {Exodus},
   crossref    = {WBC},
   number      = {3},
   address     = {Waco, TX},
   publisher   = {Word Books},
   date        = {1987},
}

@commentary{WBCLev,
   author      = {John E. Hartley},
   title       = {Leviticus},
   crossref    = {WBC},
   number      = {4},
   address     = {Nashville},
   publisher   = {Thomas Nelson},
   date        = {1992},
}

@series{SBLSCSS,
   series      = {Society of Biblical Literature Septuagint and Cognate Studies Series},
   shortseries = {SBLSCSS},
   options     = {skipbib},
}

@book{WeversGenesis1993,
   author = {John William Wevers},
   title = {Notes on the Greek Text of Genesis},
   crossref    = {SBLSCSS},
   number = {35},
   editor = {Leonard J. Greenspoon},
   publisher = {Scholars Press},
   year = {1993},
   address = {Atlanta}
}

@article{HolmstedtVT2008,
Author = {Holmstedt, Robert D.},
ISSN = {0042-4935},
Journal = {Vetus Testamentum},
shortjournal = {VT},
Keywords = {Bible. Genesis 1-11, Greek language -- Syntax, Creation -- Biblical teaching, Peer
reviewed},
Number = {1},  
Pages = {56-67}, 
Title = {The Restrictive Syntax of Genesis i 1},
Volume = {58}, 
Year = {2008},
}

\end{filecontents}
   
\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginBibliography{\def\abx@str{abx@lstr}}
\makeatother
   
\usepackage{xparse}
   
\begin{document}
   
\null\vfill
   
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
Cite WBCExod.\footcite[1]{WBCExod} Cite WBCLev.\footcite[2]{WBCLev} Cite Wevers.                               
\footcite[3]{WeversGenesis1993} Cite Holdstedt.\footcite[4]{HolmstedtVT2008}

\clearpage
\printbibliography%
\end{document}
```

Here is the output. The footnotes and list of abbreviations is correct, but there should not be abbreviations in the bibliography.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\AtBeginBibliography{\def\abx@str{abx@lstr}}` affects strings not fields, so it won't help you.

There's lots of ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to clear the various `short…` fields at every bibliography item. Then things will fall back to the unabbreviated field:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{shortseries}%
  \clearfield{shortjournal}}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@series{WBC,
  series      = {Word Biblical Commentary},
  shortseries = {WBC},
  options     = {skipbib},
}
@commentary{WBCExod,
  author      = {John I. Durham},
  title       = {Exodus},
  crossref    = {WBC},
  number      = {3},
  address     = {Waco, TX},
  publisher   = {Word Books},
  date        = {1987},
}
@commentary{WBCLev,
  author      = {John E. Hartley},
  title       = {Leviticus},
  crossref    = {WBC},
  number      = {4},
  address     = {Nashville},
  publisher   = {Thomas Nelson},
  date        = {1992},
}
@series{SBLSCSS,
  series      = {Society of Biblical Literature Septuagint and Cognate Studies Series},
  shortseries = {SBLSCSS},
  options     = {skipbib},
}
@book{WeversGenesis1993,
  author = {John William Wevers},
  title = {Notes on the Greek Text of Genesis},
  crossref    = {SBLSCSS},
  number = {35},
  editor = {Leonard J. Greenspoon},
  publisher = {Scholars Press},
  year = {1993},
  address = {Atlanta}
}
@article{HolmstedtVT2008,
  Author = {Holmstedt, Robert D.},
  ISSN = {0042-4935},
  Journal = {Vetus Testamentum},
  shortjournal = {VT},
  Keywords = {Bible. Genesis 1-11, Greek language -- Syntax, Creation -- Biblical teaching, Peer
  reviewed},
  Number = {1},  
  Pages = {56-67}, 
  Title = {The Restrictive Syntax of Genesis i 1},
  Volume = {58}, 
  Year = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{shortseries}%
  \clearfield{shortjournal}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
Cite WBCExod.\footcite[1]{WBCExod} Cite WBCLev.\footcite[2]{WBCLev} Cite Wevers.                               
\footcite[3]{WeversGenesis1993} Cite Holdstedt.\footcite[4]{HolmstedtVT2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]